# Can I build a VM and use the image on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, virtualization, parallels-desktop, virtualbox

We are going to have over a hundred MacBooks in our school. We would like to create a master image with all our base settings and applications so that it can be installed on every new MacBook that comes in.

We use Cisco Meraki to send out settings to them right now, and that will stay.

We also intend to use Bittorrent Sync to add new Applications to the MacBooks as and when. It is just a 'Gold Master' image that we want to create and keep updated.

Can a VM be created (with Parallels, VirtualBox, other?) and be exported and installed onto the MacBooks? We use the restore feature from Disk Utility to install images usually, just this time we want a usable VM to keep updated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you may be able to do this with OS X Server.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the Profile Management option that is included in OS X Server.

It has all of the described above features and it is really easy to operate with.

Take a look at https://www.apple.com/ca/osx/server/ it's $22.99 CAD.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AutoDMG](https://github.com/MagerValp/AutoDMG).  You can use a base OS X installer and add updates and packages to it.  This would be a never booted machine that mimics fresh out of the box, with custom settings.

[image]